# why does my code isn't work in sqlite3 library?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("amine.db")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AMI(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,NAME TEXT,SALARY REAL)""")
c.execute("INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,"AMINE",1000)")

conn.execute("COMMIT")
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM AMI""")
print(next(c))
```

**
I'm start learning "sqlite3" in pyton I write this code to create a table cotain salaries
when I excute it I have the folowing error *c.execute("INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,"AMINE",1000)")*
**

Comment: `c.execute` must have some return code, check that!

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
"INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,"AMINE",1000)"
```

In this part here, you are using double quotes inside a double quote string. This won't work, as python will interpret it as two separate strings with an unknown 'Amine' in the middle. You have three options to prevent this from happening:

Using single quotes for the outer string:

```py
'INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,"AMINE",1000)'
```

Using backslash before you use the inner double quotes:

```py
"INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,\"AMINE\",1000)"
```

Using triple quotes in the outer string:

```py
"""INSERT INTO AMI(ID,NAME,SALARY) VALUES(102,"AMINE",1000)"""
```

You may check that these actually work by looking at the syntax coloring.